# how can I use '$$' as column data in a db2 update query when running in script

Tags: linux, shell, db2, sh, pid

I have to run an update query in shell script

```
db2 "update tablename set fam=' ' where fam='$$' ";
```

Even though the table has fam='$$' I'am getting the below message as:

No row found for FETCH,UPDATE or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.

this is because "$$" is considered as PID ie process id. So how can I handle this

Comment: Try escaping. That works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
db2 "update tablename set fam=' ' where fam='\$\$' ";
```

You need to escape special characters.